# Html.ActionLink do not pass parameter to another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

In my index page I have A html.ActionLink like this:

```
    <table>
      <tr>    
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TestInstanceID)
        </td>
        <td>
       @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.TestInstanceID }) |
       @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.TestInstanceID }) |
       @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.TestInstanceID })|
    @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Create","StudentTestMark", new {id = item.TestInstanceID}, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

which will pass the TestInstanceID to StudentTestMark Controller Create Action.
but when I Run it. id is Null.

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        // Get TestInstance
        var testInstance = tt.GetByID(id);
        ........
   }
```

An exception of type `'System.NullReferenceException'` occurred in SHub.dll but was not handled in user code

Can't figure out what is wrong here, Please help.

Comment: Are you sure `id` is `null` and not `tt`?  The error message, given the minimal code shown, suggests that `tt` is `null`.  What debugging have you done to confirm this?

Comment: I put a break point and check the value while debugging.

Comment: What is the URL of the link generated by this `ActionLink`?  I'm still suspicious also of the exception.  Passing a `null` value to a method doesn't produce that exception, dereferencing a `null` value does.

Comment: I Can't tell URL, as page not loaded, this is  from the Local window :  Name/ Value / Type =>   id/null/ int?

Comment: If no page loads, then where is the actual problem happening?  How are you *making* the request to the action method in the first place?  What does the posted code have to do with it?  (Since the posted code is to generate a page, but you claim no page is loaded.)  If that request contains no value for `id` then of course `id` would be `null`.

Comment: I find Problem as in   RounteConfig.cs it change the parameter name from id to testInstanceid .   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Create",
                url: "StudentTestMark/Create/{testInstanceid}",
                defaults: new
                              {
                                  controller = "StudentTestMark",
                                  action = "Create",
                                  classRoomID = UrlParameter.Optional
                              }
                     );
 Comment out it, then fixed issue.